# Proving a set of points are boundary points of a set

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, complex-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I have the $D=$ set {$|z-2+5i|<7,\text{Im}(z)>0$}. I sketched it in Desmos, the overlapping region represents the set. I need to check the properties below of this set.

[image]

Boundary points - Just the union of these sets:
$$\underbrace{\{|z-2+5i|<7,Im(z)=0\}}_{A_1} \cup \underbrace{\{|z-2+5i|=7,Im(z)>0\}}_{A_2}
$$

How do I prove that these points are actually boundary points though? If I can call the two separate sets that I take union of $A_1$ and $A_2$, then for $z \in A_1$ (or $A_2$), $z$ is a boundary point of $D$ if for every $r>0$, we have $B(z,r) \cap A != \emptyset$ and $B(z,r) \cap (\mathbb C \text{without} A) != \emptyset$.

How do I show this though?

Comment: I cleaned up your mathjax, and added notations for $A_1$ and $A_2$. You can revert it all if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll give a detailed proof for the case $z \in A_1$.

Given $z$ such that $|z-2+5i|<7$ and $Im(z)=0$, and given $r>0$, your job is to write down an appropriate formula for some $w$ (expressed in terms of $z$ and $r$) and use that formula to prove that three inequalities are true:
$$|w-2+5i|<7 \quad\text{and}\quad Im(w)>0 \quad\text{and}\quad |z-w|<r
$$
You only need one value of $w$, so you want to choose $w$ in as straightforward and easy a manner as is possible.

One immediate observation is that if you take $w = z + \delta i$ for some value $\delta \in (0,r)$ then the two inqualities $Im(w)>0$ and $|z-w|<r$ are pretty obviously true.

But on top of that there is another constraint on $\delta$: you have to choose $\delta$ sufficiently small so that $|(z+\delta i) - 2 + 5i| < 7$.

This is where an application of triangle inequality is useful:
$$|(z+\delta i) - 2 + 5i| < |z-2+5i| + |\delta i| = |z-2+5i| + \delta
$$
If you set the right hand side $<7$ then you get
$$|z-2+5i|+\delta < 7
$$
and solve for $\delta$ to get
$$\delta < 7 - |z-2+5i|
$$
And notice: the right hand side is a positive number.

So now all the pieces are in place: all you have to do is to choose $\delta \in (0,r)$ so that $\delta < 7 - |z-2+5i|$, for example
$$\delta = \frac{1}{2} \text{min}\{r,7-|z-2+5i|\}
$$
Using this value of $\delta$, the number $w=z+\delta i$ satisfies all three inequalities needed so that $w\in B(z,r) \cap A_1$.

Perhaps you can now do the case $z \in A_2$ yourself.